# accessing a resource dictionary in code wpf

Tags: wpf, uri, resourcedictionary

The same line of code in the same assembly works for one test fixture but not another. Here is the line of code:

```
var dic = new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyApp.Wpf;component/ImageResources.xaml") };
```

The error I get in the other test fixture is System.UriFormatException : Invalid URI: Invalid port specified.

The uri string also works in xaml. Is there a better way to load a resource dictionary in code?

Cheers,
Berryl

=== UPDATE ===

As I found in [this posting](http://techfilth.blogspot.com/2010/01/dynamic-controltemplate-in-silverlight.html), an Invalid port was occurring because the pack scheme wasn't registered, which can be done with code like so:

```
if (!UriParser.IsKnownScheme("pack"))
     UriParser.Register(new GenericUriParser(GenericUriParserOptions.GenericAuthority), "pack", -1);
```

I am guessing that the test fixture that was able to load the dictionary with the pack scheme without error is because the SUT is a user control there, and is somehow loading resources when an instance of the user control is created.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

What I use is with UriKind like

```
var resource = new ResourceDictionary
{
    Source = new Uri("/myAssemblyName;component/Themes/generic.xaml",
                     UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
};
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

@Prince Ashitaka answer tells you how to correct your URI

However the preferred way of accessing a ResourceDictionary is that in XAML you add it on as a merged dictionary

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ImageResources.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

then you can access it via code using the `TryFindResource(string Key)` from any code behind file