# Use Style from other Assembly in Codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a cs-project-file which has a `ResourceDictionary` within. The Markup of the `ResourceDictionary` looks like:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="BaseLib.Services.TabControlServices.TabStyles"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/BaseLib.WPF.Skinning;component/BaseStyles.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In this `ResourceDictionary` I'm loading another `ResourceDictionary` which is located in another assembly. The part I want to use looks like:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="tabItemStyle">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="15,0,0,0"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" />
                    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" Grid.Column="0"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                            <Button Grid.Column="1" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                    Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="Top" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    Padding="-4,-4,0,0" Command="{Binding CloseTabCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabItem}}">
                                <Image Source="{x:Static imageProvider:Images.Close}" Width="14" Height="14" />
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource borderColor}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now I'm creating a new `TabItem` in cs-code like:

```
TabItem tabItem = new TabItem
{
   Header = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
};
tabControl.Items.Add(tabItem);
tabItem.IsSelected = true;
```

Now I want to assign the tabItemStyle to the code-generated-`TabItem`.

I tried:

```
tabItem.Style = Application.Current.FindResource("tabItemStyle") as Style;
```

but unfortunately this doesn't work. I get an `Exception`: The resource "tabItemStyle" could not be found.

My question now is:
How can I use a Style in cs-code which is located in another assembly?

Answer (score 0):

Since you merged the dictionary that has the resource into the xaml of that same control.  Try:

```
this.FindResource("tabItemStyle") as Style;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself with the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553329/accessing-a-resource-dictionary-in-code-wpf):

My code to assign the Style now looks like:

```
ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary
{
    Source = new Uri("/BaseLib.Services.TabControlServices;component/TabStyles.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
};
tabItem.Style = resourceDictionary["TabItemStyle"] as Style;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow the below steps.
1. Add reference to assembly in the project where you try to use the style
2. Add the main resource dictionary in the App.xaml
as follows

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/BaseLib.WPF.Skinning;component/BaseStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>      
</Application.Resources>
```

3. Then try to add the style in your code as you mentioned above.